# Flex-wrap and alignment

Tags: css, flexbox

I have a div in flexbox with 2 elements and space-between between them. I have also a `flex-wrap` to the container and a flex auto for each element.

Is there a way to make the first element having a text alignment on the left before it wrap and after a text alignment to the center.

The problem is that I don't know when elements are wrapping.

Here an example : https://jsfiddle.net/bj9km7vg/1/

```
.align-center{
   text-align: center; // it have to be visible only when the div is wrap and 100% of the with
}
```

Thanks all,

Comment: no-one knows, you can't *detect* wrapping in CSS...

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] snippet of your code in your question in order that we can at least attempt to look for possibilities, workarounds or, if necessary, some manner of hack that *might* help solve your problem?

Comment: @DavidThomas I update my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this differently and no need to think about `text-align` but about the element width since it's only one line. Basically your text will always be centred but the width will either fit the content or be full width:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header div:first-child {
  text-align:center; /*center by default*/
  flex-grow:1; /*will be full width after the wrap*/
}
header div:last-child {
  flex-grow:100; /*make it consume more space to have a left alignment before wrap*/
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
li {
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="align-center">
    <a href="">Have to be align</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

**Update**

To control the margin you can consider a pseudo element inside the second container:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

header div:first-child {
  text-align:center; /*center by default*/
  flex-grow:1; /*will be full width after the wrap*/
}
header div:last-child {
  flex-grow:100; /*make it consume more space to have a left alignment before wrap*/
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}


ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow:1;
}
li {
  margin: 0 1em;
}

header div:last-child::before {
  content:"";
  width:6em; /*your margin*/
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="align-center">
    <a href="">Have to be align</a>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
      <li>item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about it but there is a problem. My elements are space-between because I have to respect a margin between them. So I set a margin/padding on one element, this margin/padding is undesirable when it wraps.

Comment: @chles space-between has no effect in your code when you set flex:auto (remove it from the intial code and you will see)

Comment: You are right. The problem is the margin I need between elements when it's not wrap.

Comment: interesting but this space corresponding to the margin is still visible on the second line when it wrap. I'm not sure there is a solution...

Comment: @chles no, you won't find an accurate solution covering all your needs, you will have to *hack* around it to obtain what need. By the way, the space is visible and then it disppear when you reduce the size. You can probably consider media query to what you want

Comment: Yes I will think about it. Thanks for your help !